# Why does TinyXml2 put XMLDeclaration at the end?

Tags: c++, tinyxml2

I'm using [TinyXml2 v8.0.0](https://github.com/leethomason/tinyxml2/releases/tag/8.0.0) to create an XML buffer to send to an API. The example includes a declaration. I'm implementing this with:

```
XMLDocument doc;
doc.InsertEndChild(doc.NewDeclaration());
XMLElement* pRoot = doc.NewElement("Stuff");
doc.InsertFirstChild(pRoot);
```

The documentation for [`NewDeclaration`](https://leethomason.github.io/tinyxml2/classtinyxml2_1_1_x_m_l_document.html#aee2eb3435923f5494dcc70ac225b60a2) states:

> If the `text` param is `null`, the standard declaration is used.:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> ```

You can see this as a test in https://github.com/leethomason/tinyxml2/blob/master/xmltest.cpp#L1637

But when I print the buffer out the declaration has been placed at the end of the buffer after a newline:

```
<Stuff>
</Stuff>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? I'd expect it to be at the start of the buffer with no newline.

Comment: Looks like tinyxml is just plain broken in that regard. Consider another tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, that's because you told it to put the declaration as the `EndChild` and the `Stuff` element as the `FirstChild`.

Comment: I previously tried adding the declaration with `InsertFirstChild` but it didn't make a difference. However, your suggestion works. Maybe `InsertFirstChild` always adds to the start?

Comment: @parsley72 if you look it up, you will see that InsertFirstChild always adds to the start, and InsertEndChild always adds to the end.